# Seq2Seq model return same vector for all sentences

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I'm trying to generate an abstractive text summarization. I'm using word2vec for embedding and bi-lstm with 2 layer in encoder and bi-lstm with 1 layer in decoder, and also I'm using Attention. I trained the model and it always return same vector for all sentences of input. How can I fix this problem?

Training Code

```
latent_dim = 185
embedding_dim=128

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(int(art_max_length),))

#embedding layer
enc_emb=Embedding(input_vocab_size+1,embedding_dim, weights=[x_emb_matrix_reduce],trainable=False)(encoder_inputs)

#encoder lstm 1
encoder_bi_lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_dim,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   dropout=0.4,
                                   recurrent_dropout=0.4), 
                                 merge_mode="concat")
encoder_output1, forward_state_h1, forward_state_c1, backward_state_h1, backward_state_c1 = encoder_bi_lstm1(enc_emb)
encoder_states1 = [forward_state_h1, forward_state_c1, backward_state_h1, backward_state_c1]

#encoder lstm 2
encoder_bi_lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_dim,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   dropout=0.4,
                                   recurrent_dropout=0.4), 
                                 merge_mode="concat")
encoder_output2, forward_state_h2, forward_state_c2, backward_state_h2, backward_state_c2 = encoder_bi_lstm2(encoder_output1)
encoder_states2 = [forward_state_h2, forward_state_c2, backward_state_h2, backward_state_c2]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))

#embedding layer
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(output_vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, weights=[y_emb_matrix_reduce], trainable=False)
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)

decoder_bi_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_dim, 
                                  return_sequences=True, 
                                  return_state=True,
                                  dropout=0.4,
                                  recurrent_dropout=0.2),
                                 merge_mode="concat")
decoder_outputs, decoder_fwd_state_h1, decoder_fwd_state_c1, decoder_back_state_h1, decoder_back_state_c1 = decoder_bi_lstm(dec_emb,initial_state=encoder_states2)
decoder_states = [decoder_fwd_state_h1, decoder_fwd_state_c1, decoder_back_state_h1, decoder_back_state_c1]

# Attention layer
attn_layer = AttentionLayer(name='attention_layer')
attn_out, attn_states = attn_layer([encoder_output2, decoder_outputs])

# Concat attention input and decoder LSTM output
decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_layer')([decoder_outputs, attn_out])

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

epochs = 75
batch_size = 3
learning_rate = 0.001
initial_accumulator_value = 0.1
name = 'Adagrad'
clipnorm = 1.0

opt = Adagrad(learning_rate=learning_rate, initial_accumulator_value=initial_accumulator_value, name=name, clipnorm=clipnorm)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='auto', verbose=1,patience=10)
history=model.fit(x_tr, y_tr, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[es], steps_per_epoch=250, validation_steps=10, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
```

Inference Code

```
reverse_target_word_index = y_tokenizer.index_word
reverse_source_word_index = x_tokenizer.index_word
target_word_index = y_tokenizer.word_index

# Encode the input sequence to get the feature vector
encoder_model = Model(inputs=encoder_inputs, outputs=[encoder_output2, forward_state_h2, forward_state_c2, backward_state_h2, backward_state_c2])

# Decoder setup
# Below tensors will hold the states of the previous time step
decoder_state_input_h_fwd = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_h_bwd = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))

decoder_state_input_c_fwd = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c_bwd = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))

decoder_hidden_state_input = Input(shape=(art_max_length,latent_dim*2))

# Get the embeddings of the decoder sequence
dec_emb2= dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)

# To predict the next word in the sequence, set the initial states to the states from the previous time step
decoder_outputs2, decoder_fwd_state_h2, decoder_fwd_state_c2, decoder_back_state_h2, decoder_back_state_c2 = decoder_bi_lstm(dec_emb2, initial_state=[decoder_state_input_h_fwd, decoder_state_input_h_bwd, decoder_state_input_c_fwd, decoder_state_input_c_bwd])
decoder_states2 = [decoder_fwd_state_h2, decoder_fwd_state_c2, decoder_back_state_h2, decoder_back_state_c2]

#attention inference
attn_out_inf, attn_states_inf = attn_layer([decoder_hidden_state_input, decoder_outputs2])
decoder_inf_concat = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat')([decoder_outputs2, attn_out_inf])

# A dense softmax layer to generate prob dist. over the target vocabulary
decoder_outputs2 = decoder_dense(decoder_inf_concat)

# Final decoder model
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + [decoder_hidden_state_input, decoder_state_input_h_fwd, decoder_state_input_h_bwd, decoder_state_input_c_fwd, decoder_state_input_c_bwd],
    [decoder_outputs2] + decoder_states2)
```

Code to generate summary

```
def seq2summary(input_seq):
    newString=''
    for i in input_seq:
            if((i[0]!=0) and (i[0]!=target_word_index['sostok']) and (i[0]!=target_word_index['eostok'])):
                newString=newString+reverse_target_word_index[i[0]]+' '
    return newString

def seq2text(input_seq):
    newString=''
    for i in input_seq:
        if(i!=0):
            newString=newString+reverse_source_word_index[i]+' '
    return newString

def decode_sequence(input_seq):
    e_out, e_h_fwd, e_c_fwd, e_h_bwd, e_c_bwd = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)
    
    # Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
    target_seq = np.zeros((1,1))

    # Populate the first word of target sequence with the start word.
    target_seq[0, 0] = target_word_index['sostok']

    stop_condition = False
    decoded_sentence = ''
    
    while not stop_condition:
        output_tokens, h_fwd, c_fwd, h_bwd, c_bwd = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + [e_out, e_h_fwd, e_c_fwd, e_h_bwd, e_c_bwd])

        return output_tokens[0, -1, :]
        # Sample a token
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
        
        sampled_token = reverse_target_word_index[sampled_token_index]

        if(sampled_token!='eostok'):
            decoded_sentence += ' '+sampled_token

        # Exit condition: either hit max length or find stop word.
        if (sampled_token == 'eostok'  or len(decoded_sentence.split()) >= (high_max_length-1)):
            stop_condition = True

        # Update the target sequence (of length 1).
        target_seq = np.zeros((1,1))
        target_seq[0, 0] = sampled_token_index

        # Update internal states 
        e_h_fwd, e_c_fwd, e_h_bwd, e_c_bwd = h_fwd, c_fwd, h_bwd, c_bwd
    
    return decoded_sentence
```

Results of vectors:

```
e_h_fwd
Result:
array([[-0.00384058, -0.0084216 ,  0.00099799, -0.00328317, -0.00355412,
         0.01573788, -0.00565114,  0.0002754 , -0.01011071,  0.03385576,
         0.01035002,  0.0010401 ,  0.01606524,  0.00338535, -0.0208919 ,
         0.002799  , -0.00558226, -0.00252697, -0.00916545,  0.00482792,
         0.00838646, -0.00736981, -0.00089604, -0.00780456,  0.00439578,
         0.02386101, -0.01245494,  0.0068648 , -0.01109423, -0.00279979,
        -0.0048555 ,  0.00291485, -0.00111228,  0.0121593 ,  0.00718876,
        -0.00367533,  0.00612858,  0.0026198 , -0.00990033, -0.00372838,
         0.01660432,  0.01064453,  0.01216934, -0.01671972, -0.021307  ,
         0.00358878, -0.00851676,  0.00872963, -0.00098289, -0.00512723,
         0.00447382, -0.00086343,  0.00142587, -0.01713295, -0.01154616,
        -0.00318079, -0.0213894 ,  0.01909565,  0.00537347,  0.00287433,
         0.00013318,  0.01882311, -0.00919805, -0.01009239, -0.01000161,
         0.00729822, -0.00228036,  0.01970326, -0.00668583,  0.01141307,
        -0.00155173, -0.00519767, -0.005886  ,  0.00621226,  0.0005807 ,
        -0.00401507, -0.02050336, -0.0063515 , -0.0088415 ,  0.01226105,
         0.00378229,  0.00897009, -0.00173353, -0.00694196,  0.00197844,
        -0.0178321 ,  0.00554329,  0.01416476, -0.01519079,  0.00422954,
        -0.00771015,  0.00344123, -0.01047825, -0.00756182, -0.00108388,
        -0.01648704,  0.00209498,  0.0071196 , -0.01291664, -0.00549853,
        -0.01216177,  0.0046125 ,  0.00120374, -0.00372009,  0.01676877,
        -0.00930131, -0.00677394, -0.0162948 , -0.00530502, -0.01685343,
         0.01167075,  0.0062821 , -0.01340364,  0.00760005, -0.0337769 ,
         0.00708523, -0.00263025,  0.00446939,  0.02564106, -0.00254333,
        -0.00707568,  0.01608927,  0.00716687, -0.00965973, -0.00327503,
        -0.00604013,  0.0175317 ,  0.01505202, -0.00426429, -0.00377769,
        -0.00929095, -0.01969613,  0.00719869, -0.01020684,  0.01040385,
         0.01139158, -0.0043503 , -0.00274339, -0.00616975, -0.01331878,
         0.00295496, -0.01160615, -0.00336138,  0.00886331, -0.02004485,
         0.01137386,  0.00428817, -0.00449507, -0.00655314, -0.01015342,
         0.02188095,  0.00309571,  0.00742747,  0.02219234,  0.00236926,
        -0.00491316,  0.01939732,  0.01722919,  0.00388572,  0.02340838,
        -0.01717703, -0.00525931,  0.01344595, -0.00262558,  0.01469047,
         0.0196475 ,  0.01402889, -0.0011783 , -0.01755165, -0.01247887,
         0.01138979,  0.00034305,  0.00225358, -0.01848649, -0.01921862,
         0.0028248 , -0.01087625,  0.00121242, -0.02166731,  0.01230442,
         0.01093107,  0.01236717, -0.01110782, -0.00536899, -0.01232667]],
      dtype=float32)

output_tokens 
Result:
array([[[6.1362894e-06, 5.7854427e-06, 5.8488249e-06, ...,
         5.7374464e-06, 5.7320071e-06, 5.7324951e-06]]], dtype=float32)

np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
Result:
0
```

Comment: Which part of the code is producing the same vector output? Can you add some training outputs?

Comment: The return of encoder_model and decoder_model. Code part ENCODER: e_out, e_h_fwd, DECODER: e_c_fwd, e_h_bwd, e_c_bwd = encoder_model.predict(input_seq) and output_tokens, h_fwd, c_fwd, h_bwd, c_bwd = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + [e_out, e_h_fwd, e_c_fwd, e_h_bwd, e_c_bwd])

Comment: np.argmax of output_tokens is always equal to 0, so, I cant predict summary text with this array which is the same for all sentences.

Comment: Have you been able to fix it? I am facing similar problem with attention decoder